# Laravel's Blade not working correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I've just started a fresh Laravel 5.3 project with Homestead and I'm trying to set up a pretty simple structure for my site but I've ran into an unexpected issue.

```
- resources
-- views
--- layouts
------- master.blade.php
--- partials
------- home.blade.php
------- about.blade.php

-- index.blade.php
```

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{URL::asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  <script src="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

For some reason, the content between the `<head>` tags is output into the `<body>` tags.

[image]

index.blade.php - extends the master

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@include('partials.nav')

@section('content')

    <p>yes</p>

@endsection
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the the view extending master.blade.php?

Comment: as mentioned above but also whats the index.blade.php file outside the resources folder etc

Comment: Added, please see the updated section

Comment: it looks like your `extends` is wrong in index.blade.php.  you have `@extends('layouts.master')` but according to your dir structure, you should have `@extends('layout.master')`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. It's actually `@extends('layouts.master')` in my project. I've updated it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@include('partials.nav') should be in the master.blade.php. When extending a template, Laravel have wired strategy placing the included templates when it's not yielded.

Comment: So it's not possible to use includes what so ever when using an extension?

Comment: Good catch, ClearBoth. Ashley, you can include while extending but you should do it inside a @section scope.

Comment: @AshleyBrown you can find more information about this here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-a-layout. Mostly child template will have sections from the master templates.